# Write a unix command to count total number of word in first n lines of file?

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing

How can I count the words in the first `3` lines?

input:

```
There are many systems which are Unix-like in their architecture. 
Not able among these are the GNU/Linux distributions. 
The distinctions between Unix and Unix-like systems.
For distinctions between SUS branded UNIX architectures and other similar architectures, see Unix-like.
```

output: `28`

Comment: Use `head` command to get proper number of lines and then use `wc` command (btw: wc is abbr. of word count)

Comment: The count `28` is for the first three lines of that text, right?

Comment: Does the text really have "_Not able_" or did you miscopy that from "_Notable_"? Quite a difference in meaning (and word count)

Comment: There might be also a concern about definition of "word". Is "Unix-like" one word or two?
Please specify exactly for what input and now many lines

Comment: @DevilaN the words are different unix like and it is not able . Every word is counted individually.

Comment: "Noteable"
 not "not able"

Comment: Please don't just hand it the code that we give you. Practice with more examples. If you don't you will hit a wall later in the course. Next time mark with homework, and ask for tips, E.g. which man pages to read.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk one-liner :

```
awk ' { gsub("[-/]"," ") } NR<4 { w+=NF };END { print w }' <filename>
```

Comment: (1) The question shows **`-`** and **`/`** being used as word separators.  The OP might really want some other non-alphanumeric characters to be used as word separators (e.g., Science&Technology, Ben&Jerry’s, Unix&Linix) but they don’t say so — so why does your answer accept **`|`** as a word separator? (2) This could be simplified: `awk '{ gsub("[-/]"," "); w+=NF }; NR==3 { print w; exit }'`.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' , yeah , you are right. But i mistakenly used "|" as if its an OR operator.Will delete it now.Thanks for notifying...

Comment: I think this is a good and compact answer; I would just recommend one thing: to use `FNR` instead of `NR`. Although the OP obviously wants to inspect only one file, other people looking for a similar solution might be interested in counting the words on the first four lines of multiple files (as in `awk '<your code>'  <file1> <file2> ...`, you never know ;) ) and may be confused about the results. I also had to adapt a little to use `FNR` instead of `NR` when the latter was not specifically required, but it really helps to make answers helpful to even more people :)

Comment: yes FNR is generous option , its good to use it ...will always use it in future ..thank you for suggesting it ...

Answer (score 0):

```
$ head -n 3 file | tr -s '/ -' '\n\n\n' | wc -l
      28
```

The count `28` seems to be the count that you would get for the first three lines of the given text if you delimit words by spaces, dashes, and slashes.

The command above will split the three first lines into one such word per line by replacing each space, dash, and slash with a newline (and removing multiple consecutive newlines using the `-s` option  with `tr`), and then count the number of lines produced by this splitting.

If you use the more natural `head -n 3 file | wc -w`, you would get `25` words.  This is because `wc -w` only counts words delimited by whitespace and would consider both `Unix-Like` and `GNU/Linux` as a single words.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `grep` or compatible:

```
<myfile head -n 3 | grep -aEo '\w+' | wc -l
```

*words* in that case being sequences of one or more alphanumerical characters or underscores.

Answer (score -2):

```
head -n 4 myfile | wc -w
```

myfile is input file, 4 is first 4 lines

Comment: Note that this may give you something other than `28` as a response. This means that you can't rely on `wc -w` for the word counting.